# JSF 2 equivalent of IBM's hx:scriptCollector pre- and postRender

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere

I am migrating an old JSF application from WebSphere to JBoss: the old version uses an IBM implementation of JSF. My question concerns the following component:

```
<hx:scriptCollector id="aScriptCollector"
        preRender="#{aBean.onPageLoadBegin}" postRender="#{aBean.onPageLoadEnd}">
```

To reproduce the preRender behavior in JSF 2 I use a binding for the form (s. [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/211269/JSF/java/Load-every-JSF-Page)). My questions:

1) Do you know a trick for simulating postRender in JSF 2?

2) Do you think is the trick I am using for preRender "clean"?

Thanks a lot for your help! 
Bye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closest what you can get to achieve **exactly** the same hooks is

```
<f:view beforePhase="#{bean.beforePhase}" afterPhase="#{bean.afterPhase}">
```

with

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId == PhaseId. RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // ...
    }
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId == PhaseId. RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

The `preRender` can be achieved in an easier manner, put this anywhere in your view:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.preRenderView}" />
```

with

```
public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

*(the argument is optional, you can omit it if never used)*

---

There's no such thing as `postRenderView`, but you can easily create custom events. E.g.

```
@NamedEvent(shortName="postRenderView")
public class PostRenderViewEvent extends ComponentSystemEvent {

    public PostRenderViewEvent(UIComponent component) {
        super(component);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class PostRenderViewListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getApplication().publishEvent(context, PostRenderViewEvent.class, context.getViewRoot());
    }

}
```

which you register in `faces-config.xml` as

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.PostRenderViewListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

then you can finally use

```
<f:event type="postRenderView" listener="#{bean.postRenderView}" />
```

with

```
public void postRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC! Thank you very much for your answer, illuminating as usual! :) Unfortunately I have problems invoking the postRenderView() method. I did exactly as you wrote but it does not get invoked. If I replace in my f:event code the type="postRenderView" by "preRenderView" the method gets invoked (as if it were a preRenderView of course).. the afterPhase() of the PostRenderViewListener gets invoked as well. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: Is `<f:event>` enclosed in `<f:metadata>`? This way it'll be attached to `UIViewRoot` (which is been passed in `publishEvent()` call). Otherwise you'd need to walk through the entire component tree and publish this for all individual components of the view tree which is relatively expensive. The `preRenderView` has as a standard event type already special treatment by `UIComponent`, so it's not mandatory for it to be placed in `<f:metadata>` in order to be attached directly to `UIViewRoot`.

Comment: No it is not enclosed in f:metadata (at least explicitly?): anyway I just changed the constructor to public PostRenderViewEvent(UIViewRoot component) {super(component);} and now works. Is it correct like this?

Comment: Oh! That can also :) Good find.