# migration from websphere to glassfish

Tags: jsf, glassfish, websphere

dears,

I'm currently trying to migrate a project from websphere to glassfish. by replacing hx tags with normal jsf tags.

I have two tags that i cannot have an alternative to :

```
<hx:scriptCollector
    id="scriptCollector1" preRender="#{pc_Main.onPageLoad}"> </hx:scriptCollector>
```

and

```
</hx:requestLink>
```

kindly if there is any jsf tag that can be used instead let me know. because it will take time to start from scratch

Comment: These are 'websphere tags', but most likely from some IBM framework.

Comment: @Kukeltje i know they are websphere tags, i need to replace them with jsf tags so that i can run the application on glassfish. is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF 2 equivalent of IBM's hx:scriptCollector postRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118103/jsf-2-equivalent-of-ibms-hxscriptcollector-postrender)

Comment: With posting 'hx:scriptCollector ibm' in google I very easily found a duplicate in Stackoverflow....

Comment: @Kukeltje how about the preRender ?

Comment: That is also in there. Title does not seem to cover the content. I edited it already. But better think if you really need it. Seems like a very exotic case

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm sorry but what do you mean? can I use outPutscript with prerender? will it do the same thing as scriptCollector?

Comment: No idea.. I just found this 'duplicate'. And like I mentioned, try to find out why you need this. What does it do **for you**. Maybe there are other alternatives.